# Keep getting could not load Microsoft.Data.Edm

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, nopcommerce

i am using VS2015 community edition, working on a NopCommerce website, i am working on a plugin, and on my local machine everything works fine as expected, but when i depoly it live i keep getting the yellow screen with " Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Data.Edm' or one of its dependencies. The
located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. "

i do see that there is a version issue, and it tries to load version 5.6.4 from my plugin, and it shows that it loaded 5.7.0

so i tried to reference inside the plugin the older version, and it works for a while but then it crashes until i make a full deployment, and then it works for another while and crashes again.

so i want to get this fix the proper way, but i have no idea why my plugin uses a different version than the whole nop, what i see is that inside the bin folder from the project, i see the dll version of 5.7.0, but i have no clue why my plugin is looking for an older version, can anyone just give me some notes on this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your plugin you could use any package from \packages folder, for example - \packages\Microsoft.Data.Edm.5.7.0. Then all plugins in nopCommerce have an app.config file, you can copy it from any existing plugin. Also, ensure that "Copy local" properties of all third-party assembly references are set to "False" (do not copy).

Comment: thank you so much for your input, that sounds to be fixing the issue, finally, will link to this answer in the nop forum.

Answer (score 2):

The best solution worked for me is ,
1. Just clean the solution
2. Rebuild and run !